# Store template function to be called later

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

I am working on a project where I must determine if I must call a user-provided function, based on some conditions. The catch is that the provided function can have any signature. Is there any possibility to do the following using the current c++11 standard? (the code must compile using visual c++ 2010):

```
template <what do I put here?>
void functioncall(std::function<and here> f)
{
   ReturnType returnval = f(arguments);
}
```

Comment: How can you call it if you don't know the `arguments`, and what could you possibly do with the returned value?

Answer (score 2):

This is even possible in C++03, just use an unrestricted parameter:

```
template<class F>
void call(F f) // accept any callable entity
{
  ReturnType retval = f(arguments);
}
```

Comment: I do not think your solution applies here because the callable entity can have any signature. For example, I must be able to
call: 
    int f1(int y,int z){return y+z;}
    char * f2(int x) { return nullptr;}
    call(f1); call(f2);

these must both work. Am I missing something from your comment?

Comment: @razvanp: Erm... how does an *unrestricted* callable entity not allow that? Pass whatever you want and call it however you like.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? This is the first time I stumble across this term. Thank you very much.

Comment: -1 this still does not address the issue of the arguments and the return value.

Comment: @Walter: I think this is rather a problem with the OPs design. He asked how to take any callable entity, and I provided a solution for that. And since he was asking for a way to accept any possible signature, he'd better have a way to get the right arguments for the function call. For the return value, in VS2010 you can already use `auto`, as in, `auto retval = f(args);`.

Comment: @razvanp: I really don't know what I should show an example of. You can pass anything to `call` that can be called like a function.